# Duplicated actions in Shortcut App after donation INInteraction

Tags: swift, shortcut, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I created custom INIntent using SiriKit Intent Definition File, with no parameter, it is just suppose to be navigation to specific flow in my app. I selected 'Configurable in Shortcuts' as I want it to available in actions in Shortcut App.

When user is using that flow in my app I donate system about action:

```
let intent = MyIntent()
let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
interaction.donate(completion: nil)
```

The problem is that now I have two the same suggestions in Shortcut App. One is coming from configuration file and the second appears when I call donate. If I uncheck 'Configurable in Shortcuts' there will be only one but I want user to have it listed in actions even if he hasn't make it yet. What I'm potential making wrong that action is duplicated?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening or some type of fix?

Comment: The iOS 17 simulator can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yup, you are right